# How to open another form when we click on QToolButton in PyQt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

```
from settings import settings_form
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        settings_obj = settings_form()
        self.toolButton.connect(settings_obj.show())
```

Here I am trying to open settings form when the `toolbutton` is clicked. I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: argument 1 of QObject.connect() has an invalid type
```

Can you please share the correct way of opening the settings form, when I click on the `toolbutton`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these are the right ways to do it:

Either traditional way:

```
self.toolButton.connect(self.toolButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), settings_obj.show)
```

Or new way:

```
self.toolButton.clicked.connect(settings_obj.show)
```

Comment: @Juna .. Glad to be of help :)